# Filter the table with latest date having duplicate OrderId

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table:

[image]

I need to filter out the rows for which start date is latest corresponding to its order id .With reference to given table row no 2 and 3 should be the output. 
 As row 1 and row 2 has same order id and order date  but start date is later than first row. And same goes with row number 3 and 4 hence I need to take out row no 3 . I am trying to write the query in SQL server. Any help is appreciated.Please let me know if you need more details.Apologies for poor English

Comment: Do *not* tag spam unrelated products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way using a derived table.

```
select
     t.*
from 
   YourTable t
inner join
(select OrderId, max(StartDate) dt
 from YourTable
 group by OrderId) t2 on t2.dt = t.StartDate and t2.OrderId = t.OrderId
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a `ROW_NUMBER()` windowed function:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By OrderId Order By StartDate Desc) RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  *
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```

But I question the `StartDate` datatype.  It looks like these are being stored as `VARCHAR`.  If that is the case, you need to `CONVERT` the value to a `DATETIME`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  *,
            Row_Number() Over (Partition By OrderId 
                               Order By Convert(DateTime, StartDate) Desc) RN
    From    YourTable
)
Select  *
From    Cte
Where   RN = 1
```